# Interpreting the summary() of a lm() linear model in R

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I have a multiple linear regression with 4 independent variables. The summary() function returns the following:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.03039    0.16152  -0.188   0.8530    
var1         -0.96553    0.18595  -5.193 7.34e-05 ***
var2        -0.25014    0.19732  -1.268   0.2220  *  
var3         -0.40355    0.22072  -1.828   0.0851 **  
var4         0.15887    0.18559   0.856   0.4039    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5606 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7572,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6857 
F-statistic:  10.6 on 5 and 17 DF,  p-value: 9.445e-05
```

It shows that var4 is not significant. However, when I remove it from the model, the new p-value increases, R-square decreases, and the mean squared error of the model also increases

Question: Should I keep or remove var4 from the model? Will my model be criticized if I keep a non-significant independent variable? Thanks

Comment: This question is a better fit for Cross Validated, where similar methodological questions have been answered: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413606/when-to-remove-insignificant-variables or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271434/when-should-one-include-a-variable-in-a-regression-despite-it-not-being-statisti/271448#271448

Comment: Adding a variable ALWAYS reduces MSE thus increases R^2 and R^2 is inversely proportional to SSE. Use the adjusted R^2 to determine as to whether to include the variable or not. ie if the adjusted R^2 changes by alot when the variable is added/removed, then include the variable, otherwise leave it out